# PostGis stopped working: Invalid access to memory location

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have a PostgreSQL v9.3 database with PostGIS 2.1.8 running locally on Win10 Creative Update 64-Bit.
This database is running for months without any problem. I've used it yesterday afternoon.
This morning when I want to query the table with a geometry column I get this error: 
`ERROR:  could not load library "D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgis-2.1.dll": Invalid access to memory location.`

When I use pgAdmin to connect to a remote test-server with the same database I don't have this error. So it must be something with my local instance.

Of course, I already restarted my laptop and restarted the PostgreSQL service, without any luck. I checked my Windows Updates and nothing has been installed in the last two weeks.

The dll-file does exist, I have verified it.
I have no idea what is happening and how to solve this.